# Returning JSONP instead of JSON from a JSP

Tags: jsp, jsonp

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124960/how-to-simply-return-json-from-a-jsp) on setting the response type to json from a jsp but I'm in need of setting the response type to jsonp for cross-domain access. Would it still be this:

`response.setContentType("application/javascript");`

and just wrapping the response from the jsp in `callbackfunction(` + content + `)` or is there something more that needs to be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best content type to serve JSONP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111302/best-content-type-to-serve-jsonp)

Comment: I saw that answer, but I was more specifically asking if there's anything else I need to do to access it correctly on the other end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had to do this. In the server side I had something like so:

```
string callbackName = queryMap['callback']; //jquery will pass in some name in our .getJSON call below
string jsonData = getJsonData();
string jsonp = callbackName + "(" + jsonData + ")";

response.SetContentType('application/javascript');
response.Send( jsonp );
```

And in the javascript it was something like so:

```
var url = getUrl() + "?callback=?";
$.getJSON(url,function(onSuccessData){ alert(onSuccessData); });
```

Comment: Thanks, we're doing something essentially equivalent to this.

Answer (score 0):

To support cross-domain access in javascript you can use
    $.support.cors = true;
Other than that you can set content-type to application/javascript for jsonp.

Comment: I found the application/javascript answer after posting this, thanks. My question was really geared toward how create the JSP so that it returns the correct jsonp data. Should it be formated by callbackfunction + '(' + content + ')' or what?

Answer (score 0):

jsp:

```
 String str = "{\"appNo\":\"" + "2" + .....+ "\"}";
    String json = "m1(" + str + ")";
    response.getWriter().write(json);
```

html:

```
 $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',    
          url: url,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          crossDomain: true,          
          cache:false,
           jsonp:"callback",
          success: function(data){  }....
   });
```

This is the code for my jsp

Comment: "This is the code for my jsp, do the result same as yours?" - You shouldn't have to ask a question to have a good answer. I recommend you be sure this is the right answer and have the confidence to say so.