# Struts2 How to Return a JSON Response

Tags: java, json, struts2, action, gson

I am currently creating a web-application where the users can fetch tags from the database as JSON,

here is my struts action

```
public String execute(){


    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String tagsAsJson = gson.toJson(audioTaggingService.findTagsByName(q));
    System.out.println(tagsAsJson);

    return "success";
}
```

UPDATE:

The `tagsAsJson` is already in a JSON format all I want is to return only that, and not the whole class action itself.

It returns something like this

This is the data I want to return to the user

```
[{"id":2,"name":"Dubstep","description":"Dub wob wob"},{"id":3,"name":"BoysIIMen","description":"A 1990s Boy Band"},{"id":4,"name":"Sylenth1","description":"A VST Plugin for FLStudio "}]
```

How do I return the `tagsAsJson` as a r JSON esponse? since that JSON response will be used by the client side code.

Comment: Have a look at this post http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-and-json-example/

Comment: ^
That have not worked for me.

Comment: It works so try again. It is just telling you to add struts2-json-plugin and use the json result type.

Comment: It converts the whole action class as JSON. I only want the String to be responded and that example gives me a lot of exceptions.

Comment: To address your update, it is in json format because you manually put it that way.  Just use the plugin. If you want slighly more work to do what you want then use a stream result... you can also use a JSP to output JSON see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124960/how-to-simply-return-json-from-a-jsp but really... just use the plugin.

Comment: I am already using the plugin but it is returning a lot of errors. I guess I'll just post that in another question.

Comment: I have the same problem. Struts 2 returns a whole action class with even request params!

Comment: **For those visiting in the future:** it makes little sense to pre-convert the data to a JSON string; instead use the built-in S2 JSON response mechanisms. Simply expose the data you want returned and the framework handles the rest.

Answer (score 23):

Use the Struts ["JSON Plugin"](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/json-plugin.html).

Quite easy, three steps:

Just include it in your maven project like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.struts2}</version>
</dependency>
```

Declare the field you'd like to return as JSON string like the field of your action, provide the getter and setter.

```
public class Struts2Action extends ActionSupport {

    private String jsonString;

    public String execute() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        jsonString = gson.toJson(audioTaggingService.findTagsByName(q));

        return "success";
    }

    public String getJsonString() {
        return jsonString;
    }

    public void setJsonString(String jsonString) {
        this.jsonString = jsonString;
    }
}
```

And, finally, put this in your XML:

```
<action name="someJsonAction" class="com.something.Struts2Action">
    <result type="json">
        <param name="noCache">true</param>
        <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
        <param name="root">jsonString</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Pay attention to `<param name="root">jsonString</param>`. This piece of xml tells Struts2 that this exact property should be considered as a root for JSON serialization. So only the named property (and below, if it's a map or whatsoever) will be returned in a JSON response.

Thanks to the JSON Plugin the content type will be correct.

"JSON Plugin" documentation is here: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/json-plugin.html

Comment: This looks like the best answer. It worked fine for me. Specially now that json-plugin has been absorbed by Struts2 as a default library.

Comment: this does not seem to work using struts 2.5 and the json result.  Had exact same setup with another library returning a json string and trying to send it back using json result.  I get  net.sf.json.JSONException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when pointing it at a String property

Comment: Beware this answer: You should NEVER have instance fields in singletons that you expect to be request-dependent. This is a nasty race condition waiting to happen.

Comment: @TylerHoppe There is no singleton here I can see--can you explain? **Note to future readers:** this warning is not relevant for normal S2 applications; there is no singleton here, and this answer is perfectly ok (delta it's doing work S2 can already do for you, which doesn't make much sense).

Answer (score 16):

Try using the response's PrintWriter.

Java

```
    public String execute()
    {
      Gson gson                    = new Gson();
      String jsonString            = gson.toJson(audioTaggingService.findTagsByName(q));
      HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();

      response.setContentType("application/json");
      response.getWriter().write(jsonString );

      return null;
   }
```

Comment: This is the most correct answer here given that he already has a JSON string. A better approach would be to create an actual `Result` to handle dealing with the `HttpServletResponse`, though.

Answer (score 2):

In Action class put below code.

```
  public class Struts2Action extends ActionSupport
  {     

    public String jsonString="";

    public String execute()
    {
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      jsonString  = gson.toJson(audioTaggingService.findTagsByName(q));
      System.out.println(jsonString);

      return "success";
   }
  }
```

In JSP put below code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<title>Struts Rais</title>

<s:property value="jsonString"/><br />
```

This will print JSON data if you want to manipulate JSON data you cat the data in var `<s:set>` tag and access the variable in entire page.

Comment: Let me know if you are looking for other thing

Comment: If the OP is looking for a JSON response, it's more likely they don't want HTML, need the content type set, etc.

Comment: this perfectly works fine. but i have ArrayList<string> jsonList; this list contains no data even though it results into success function

Answer (score 1):

To return a JSON response you need to include the **struts2-json-plugin-2.x.x.jar** file in your project build path You will need to set package **extends="json-default"** result type is **json**.

*struts2-json-plugin-2.x.x.jar file allows you to serialize the Action class attribute which has setters into a JSON object.*

Get the jar dependencies from maven

```
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

You can get the complete help from this link...

[Struts 2 and JSON response](http://www.websparrow.org/struts/struts2-and-json-integration-example)