# Autofill textbox from database based on change of dropdown list value

Tags: javascript, jsp, model-view-controller, onchange

My jsp page has a select box with all userIds. And I have two text boxes for username and Data of birth. I want to autofill the textboxes when I select a userid from dropdown list.

I have a separate Servlet class and Database class for querying.

How to automatically the textboxes when I select userid from dropdown ? And i want this textboxes to be not editable. Can someone provide me example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ntmuub80/2/) showing how to implement it:

```js
var $select = document.getElementById('slct'),
    $un = document.getElementById('un'),
    $dob = document.getElementById('dob'),
    val, arr, username, dob;

// usually this array is obtained from a server response 
arr = [
     usr1 = ['user1', 'dob1'],
     usr2 = ['user2', 'dob2'],
     usr3 = ['user3', 'dob3'],
     usr4 = ['user4', 'dob4']
    ];

$select.addEventListener('change', function(){
 val = this.value - 1; // because arrays start at 0.
 username = arr[val][0];
    dob = arr[val][1];
    $un.value = username;
    $dob.value = dob;
});
```

```html
<select id="slct">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">id 1</option>
    <option value="2">id 2</option>
    <option value="3">id 3</option>
    <option value="4">id 4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="un" disabled>
<input type="text" id="dob" disabled>
```

Comment: Thanks. How to construct the array from the servlet response rather than hardcoded array. I guess it should be a two dimensional array with userId = [username,DOB]

Comment: Well you can use AJAX to get result back as a2 dimensional array or as JSON response, I work with php not jsp but it's the same idea I will give you some examples.

Comment: just used google search and i got these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4VgHJCAKZZQ :: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2jyMzSfVLE :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046331/creating-a-json-object-in-jsp-and-using-it-with-jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124960/how-to-simply-return-json-from-a-jsp :: http://www.programming-free.com/2012/09/ajax-with-servlets-using-jquery-and-json.html :: http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/ajax-implementation-in-jsp-servlet-using-jquery-and-json/